# passing command line argument to bash shell script which is called from the c++ program

Tags: c++, bash, shell, unix

I am just calling the shell script from my c++ program.
Shell script is executing successfully. But i am not able to receive the command line arguments passed to the shell script via c++ program.

```
#include<iostream>


    int main()
    {
       system(". script.sh a b v d d");


       return 0;
    }
```

SHELL

```
echo "start | $2 | $1 | $3"
```

O/P:

```
./a.out
start |  |  |
```

Comment: Exactly what happens when you run that?

Comment: @MatsPetersson Attached the output

Answer (score 1):

The syntax you used is applied when you want to load up the contents of a shell script into your current shell. That means, load variable definitions, functions and so on.

```
system(". script.sh a b v d d");
        ^^^^^^^^^^^
```

It is *equivalent* to running:

```
system("source script.sh a b v d d");
        ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
```

You should invoke the script with one of the following syntaxes:

```
system("./script.sh a b v d d");
system("bash script.sh a b v d d");
```

---

So, when you executed your program, the only thing that happened was your script being *source*'d. Without any parameters being passed into it. Which gave you the output of running your `echo "start | $2 | $1 | $3"` without any input parameter.

Comment: Can you explain why we have to call like this

Comment: Sure! I've added an explanation. Regards!

Comment: I have used this source command earlier... In addition to the loading it will execute to the commands. Eventhough it executes commands it will not take arguments. It is equivalent to running a commands one by one. Am i right

Comment: Sourced files can take command-line arguments the same as executed scripts.